# How to step into mako template rendering

Tags: python, python-3.x, mako

I'm using python's mako.template module to render certain .tmpl files to have parametrized code injection, but I would like to be able to step in to the rendering process to see how my parametrized variables are evaluating. SO basically watching how the rendering is happening on the fly.

Is this possible? I'm not trying to debug to catch any errors, its just for monitoring.

Thanks in advance